# Setting diff tool in SourceTree permanently

Tags: git, merge, diff, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Atlassian SourceTree and I would like to use Araxis Merge as diff tool rather than source tree default. There is option to set Araxis Merge as diff tool in source tree setting but I need to set it again and again each time I start source tree. So is there a way with which I can set it permanently. I also tried to set it using SourceTree.exe.config file but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that post recently because of I has the same question (but for using p4merge) in source tree. I'm posting an answer for future reader since you probably found the solution years ago ^^

In my version (**1.9.10.0**), you go to: **Tools > Options > Diff**  - There you can change diff/merge parameters and tools to use.